# Perform SQL function on single column based on multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, dimensional-modeling, infinidb

I encounter this problem when trying to work out a dimensional database design. Basicially I haave a fact table (sale_fact) which contains a surrogate key, several foreign keys (pid for product id, cid for country id and date), and sales data. The granularity or this fact table is on daily basis. How do I sum up the sales data for weeks (or months), depending on different combinations of those foreign keys?
For example, I want to sum up sales data of product 1 in country 1 in this week (pid = 1 and cid = 1 and date = Monday), sales data of product 2 in country 2 in the same week (pid = 2 and cid = 2 and date = Monday). How do I achieve this data in one SQL? The sample result set would be like:

```
    | id | pid | cid |     date     | total |
    | 1  |  1  |  1  |  2013-11-04  |   100 |
    | 2  |  1  |  2  |  2013-11-04  |  90   |
    | 3  |  1  |  3  |  2013-11-04  |  80   |
    | 4  |  2  |  1  |  2013-11-04  |  91   |

......more data
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use something like select sum(sales) as 'total' from table where date = Monday groupby pid, cid...

Comment: It seems working like a charm. The query is much simpler than I expected. By the way, does this groupby still apply if I have a lot of foreign keys?

Comment: Groupby works irrespective of the number of foreign keys in the table. It just is a way of grouping your resulting data in a particular order you prefer. Glad I could help

Comment: If I have solved your problem then please mark the above as the answer and close the forum. Thanks Nemo